# Fetching Single Data JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

Imagine I have 3 data in my `tbl_customer` then If I click the button view, the modal will show with the data's. It's working if the button I clicked has data, Then the problem is, if the button has no data the modal didn't show. But I want to show the modal even I have no data in my `button`. Please help me out of this problem, thankyou!

Button: `<button type="button" onclick="return chk('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Add features</button>`

Here's the code:

```
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>'

<?php 
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "psbr");
$rooms_f = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM room_f"); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rooms_f)) { ?> 
<button type="button" onclick="return chk('.$row['id'].')" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Add features</button>
<?php } ?>

  function chk(id)
  {
    var roomid = document.getElementById('text_id_' + id).value;
    var dataString = 'roomid='+ roomid;
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "fetch_single3.php",
      data:dataString,
      cache:false,
      success: function(data){

       $("#modal_features").hide();
       $("#modal_sample").slideDown();
       $("#modal_sample").html(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
```

fetch_single3

```
    <?php 

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'psbr');
$rooms = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM rooms");

    $roomid = $_POST['roomid'];
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM room_f WHERE room_id='$roomid'"); 

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/feature-design.css">
<div id="modal_sample">
    <h4 class="h4" style="margin: 3%;">Room Features</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-info button">Add Feature</button>
<table id="features_table">
  <tr>
    <th width="20%">ID</th>
    <th width="49%">Feature</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['feature']; ?></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Update Feature</button> &nbsp;<button class="btn btn-warning btn-danger btn-xs ">Delete feature</button></td>
  </tr>
  <div class="add_modal" id="add_modal">
        <h4 style="margin: 5%; ">Add Feature</h4>
        <hr>
        <label style="margin: 1%;">Enter Feature name</label>
        <input type="text" id="text_featurename" name="text_featurename">
        <input type="hidden" id="text_featureid" name="text_featureid" value="<?php echo $row['room_id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return add()" id="submit">
        <button class="btn btn-default cbtn_addm">Close</button>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
<button type="button" id="btn_c"class="btn_c">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: is it throwing any errors?,check network tab and console in your browser to know any errors are rising

Comment: @DhanuK there's no error.

Comment: @DhanuK I already checked it

Comment: is it responding with error code(200) and is it sending any response data ?

Comment: I don't know that sorry :(

Comment: "It's working if the button I clicked has data"  _Which_ button?  You have many buttons in the code above.

Comment: @PatrickQ I already updated, please help me out of this problem!! :(

Comment: There is no way that this code works at all.  You are closing you PHP tag on the line above the button, and then attempting to use a PHP variable in `chk('.$row['id'].')`.  That is surely going to cause a Javascript error when you click the button.